# Alternative ways to reschedule AirAsia booking

Tags: airasia, schedule-change

I booked a direct AirAsia flight (AK) between DMK and BKI on AirAsia.com itself. When trying to reschedule, the picker cannot find any direct flights after a certain date (14 days after the flight date, which was today), even if they exist and are bookable otherwise.

**Is there an alternative way to reschedule flights?** I tried the website on desktop, mobile and the app, they all point to the same UI. I’d rather not have to go to the airport and there doesn’t seem to be a phone number.

---

No direct flight when changing the booking:

[image: no direct when rescheduling]

But it appears when booking:

[image: direct when booking]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AirAsia shut down all their call centers in 2019, all support is now exclusively online.  The main channel is their "Virtual Assistant" AVA:
https://support.airasia.com/s/?language=en_GB

Obviously it's a bot, but it can also transfer you to a human agent if needed, and that's probably your best bet.  For your particular scenario, at last check any requests to change existing bookings are automatically connected to an agent.

Comment: Thank you. I had tried it yesterday but nothing connected me to an agent. I tried again after your suggestion and was connected by writing "refund missing". They solved my issue in a few minutes after a 30-minute wait.